# headwind, tailwind, weight, density exponents for DR400/180

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff

I am trying to build a ground roll chart for Robin DR400/180 following the procedure described
http://www.eaa1000.av.org/technicl/takeoff/topaper.htm#References. Does anyone know the tailwind, headwind, weight and density exponent to use for Robin DR400/180. Nothing is published in the flight manual.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking for.  Three of the variables are external environmental conditions.  A range of weights from zero fuel to MGTOW ought to in the manual.

Comment: @MichaelHall if you look at table 1 of the attached link, there are values specific to different aircrafts. I was wondering what are these values for a Robin DR400/180

Comment: I don't think that "exponent" is the word you want.  Maybe "coefficient"?

Comment: agree, it can be coefficient, I am just re-using the same terminology to help